# How to find monotony of $x_{n+1} = \ln(1 + x_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

How do I find the monotony of the series $x_{n}=\ln(1+x_{n-1}),x_{1}=a, 0<a<1$?

I know I should do the difference between $x_{n+1}-x_{n}$ and see if it is positive or negative but I get $\ln\frac{1+x_{n}}{1+x_{n-1}}$ and I do not know what to do after. Can you help me?

Comment: The sequence is $x_1=a,x_2=\log (a+1),x_3=\log (\log (a+1)+1),x_4=\log (\log (\log (a+1)+1)+1),x_5=\log (\log (\log (\log (a+1)+1)+1)+1),\ldots$

Comment: What is your definition of $\ln (x)$?

Answer (score 2):

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\ln(1+x_n)-x_n<0$$

Let $f(x)=x-\ln{(1+x)}$, where $x>-1$.

Thus, $f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{x}{x+1}$, which says that $x_{\min}=0$.

That is, $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$.

In our case $x>0$. Thus, $\ln(1+x)-x<0$.

Comment: Ok, but why is it like that?

Comment: @Ovy Ovy I added something. See now, please.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. But let's say that someone does not know how to use derivates. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Ovy Ovy Yes of course! $\ln(1+x_n)<x_n\Leftrightarrow (1+x_n)^{\frac{1}{x_n}}<e$.

Comment: Why is it like that? Sorry but I do not understand this. Why if $(1+x_n)^{\frac{1}{x_n}}<e$ then $\ln(1+x_{n})<x_{n}$ ?

Comment: @Ovy Ovy I thought that you knew it. If you don't know this fact then I think  it's better to use derivative.

Comment: I do not know this but now you made me curious so please can you explain it to me?

Comment: @Ovy Ovy By definition $e=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and from here we can get $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}<e$, but it's very ugly way if it's new for you.